# Perfect Soap (Wsdl) web service in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am a PHP programmer, I want to create a SOAP web service using WSDL.

Please could someone suggest any simple tutorials or code that enable me to make object on Device (iPhone, Blackberry, Android) End.

Comment: *"make object on Device (iPhone, Blackberry, Android) End"* makes very little sense. PHP wouldn't be used on those devices.

Answer (score 31):

Here are some tutorials & examples of SOAP (WSDL) web service in PHP:

1. [Creating Web Services with PHP and SOAP, Part 1](http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/) (out of date - nusoap)
2. [Creating Web Services with PHP and SOAP, Part 2](http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-2/) (out of date - nusoap)
3. [wsdl2php Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20131023185211/http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/manual.php) (PHP SOAP extension)
4. [Web Services - WSDL: Creating SOAP Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150805115209/http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Web-Services-WSDL-Creating-SOAP-Server-P484.html) (PHP SOAP extension)
5. [WSDL Document Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm) (SOAP explanation, no PHP)

**Edit: For Latest Version of PHP above 5.3**

The [SoapClient class](http://php.net/soapclient) is used in latest version of PHP (5.3 & up).

It may help you.

Comment: first link is broken , needs to be updated.

Answer (score 17):

Please avoid following some the suggested links from [Tony Stark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490799/327074), they are really **out of date**.

For example, using nusoap is really a pain in the ass with a currently supported version of PHP (e.g. 5.3/5.4).

A better alternative is the [SoapClient](http://php.net/soapclient) from the native PHP SOAP extension.

Comment: i am new to php and want to host a soap service on apache. Can you provide me any client/server example based on php 5.3

Comment: The first link 'Developing Services Using PHP' (http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html) is still relevant - it uses the native SoapClient

Comment: I have noted which ones used nusoap now