# What is the correct way to add a PCTC SSR in SITA Web Services (SWS)

Tags: sws, sita

I'm trying to use the SITA Web Services to add an emergency contact to a booking. I'm using this XML, but I keep getting "013 - ACTION" error

```
<OTA_AirBookModifyRQ xmlns:="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TransactionIdentifier="" Version="2003.5.0">
<AirBookModifyRQ BookingReferenceID="JKYZJ" ModificationType="5">
    <TravelerInfo>
        <SpecialReqDetails>
            <SpecialServiceRequests>
                <SpecialServiceRequest SSRCode="PCTC" Status="11" TravelerRefNumberRPHList="1">
                    <Airline Code="XS"></Airline>
                    <Text>DOCTOR DR/XS222H.SISTER</Text>
                </SpecialServiceRequest>
            </SpecialServiceRequests>
        </SpecialReqDetails>
    </TravelerInfo>
</AirBookModifyRQ>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting "013 - ACTION" is that you are specifying "11" (which means NN -Need) as the status. Change the status to "26", which means HK - Hold Confirmed).

Note also, for PCTC the  element must be in a specific format to be correctly accepted by reservation system. See the Agent Reservation guide for more details on this.

Comment: Hello @Kevin . I am new to SITA web services and I am trying to use it with PHP. But I do not know from where to start. Can you please help me how can i call the web services and whihc credentials i need for it? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to get credentials from the airline you are working with (you must have airline approval to call these services). And as for using PHP, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490799/156477 for information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Whether SITA have any sandbox API? Meanwhile, we get the live credentials, so I can start to implement using the sandbox.